# -w flag not working for gnu compiler (make command)

Tags: macos, gcc, terminal, gnu-make

I am trying to suppress warnings for deprecated code but for some reason, running `make -w`, `make -Wno-deprecated`, `make -Wno-deprecated-declarations`, or any other flag I've found online does not work. I am on a Mac running Yosemite (10.10) with gcc version 4.2.1. and GNU make 3.81. `make` runs correctly and outputs everything it should, but I cannot get rid of those pesky warnings! Attached is the end of the output after running `make`.

[Terminal output with relevant warning messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb28B.png)

Comment: Those options are for the compiler, not for `make`! Try `make CXXFLAGS=-w`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I do need to fix them but, just for now, I need to merely not see them. You are correct.
Marc, unfortunately that did not work. It still made, but still with warning errors. Thanks for the replies though!

Comment: Without seeing your makefile there's no way we can tell you what variable you should be setting.  The variable that the built-in rules use for C++ compiler flags is `CXXFLAGS`, but your makefile could be using something completely different.  In any event, Marc is correct: you can't pass _compiler_ flags directly to _make_.  You have to find out, in your makefile, where your compiler flags are stored and change that make variable to add the new flags to suppress unwanted compiler warnings.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the info. I shall work on this. Thanks!